# Printing out a users name with their Facebook ID (Laravel 4)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a PHP application and I want to be able to print a Facebook user's name given their FB Id.  I have already pulled the FB IDs for all of the friends of a user using:

```
'friends'  => 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id&access_token='.$token->access_token
```

I have decoded and stored all of the ids in a string, like so:

```
fbid1,fbid2,fbid3, etc..
```

From this, I would like to print the image and name of the user with the specified FB ID.  I know I can print the image like so:

```html
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ $x }}/picture" alt="" height="40" width="40" class="img-rounded">
```

However, how do I print the name of the user, given the FB ID ($x in this case)?

I know I can pull the names by adding it to the fields list in the request above, but I would really rather pull it for each specific FBID like the image above.

I also know that this: `http://graph.facebook.com/$x?fields=name,first_name` achieve what I want to do if I visit the URL.  But, I would like to have the name output as a string for a specified FB ID that I can place in my HTML.

Comment: By using `/me/friends?fields=id` you have explicitly stated that the id is the only thing you are interested in. Just remove `?fields=id`, and you will get id _and name_ of your friends by this one API call already.

Comment: I like having the array decoded with just the fbids (fbid1,fbid2,fbid3) as a string that I can explode into an array.  I want to pull the name when I pull a specific fbid and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this elsewhere.  The simplest way to do this is:

```
<?php echo json_decode(file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$x))->name; ?>
```

Where $x is the fbid of the user you want the name of.  This was the simplest solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `cUrl`, you can simply save the json_encoded output of `http://graph.facebook.com/$x?fields=name,first_name` in a variable, eg: `$fname` `lname`; and use them in your html as-

```
<p>Hi <span><?php echo $fname; ?></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of this?